# hook_views_data TIMESTAMP field is empty

Tags: views, 7

I'm using hook_views_data in my custom module to show the formatted date of a table in mysql. Using the example in the [api](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7) I have text working but my TIMESTAMP in the donationDate column shows up blank.

MySql reports it is a TIMESTAMP field and it's showing me '2015-04-16 18:41:09'. When I change out the below to the string options it shows me the string representation so I know it's passing data from that column. I've played with the options in setting up this custom view but none of the date options seem to make a difference. I've looked at Google but none point me to what I might be doing wrong. How should I troubleshoot it?

```
function manage_donations_views_data() {
  $data['GeneralDonations']['table']['group'] = t('Donations');
  $data ['GeneralDonations']['table']['base'] = array(
    'field' => 'donationId',
    'help' => t('List of recent donations'),
    'title' => t('All donations'),
    'weight' => -10,
  );


  $data['GeneralDonations']['donationForm'] = array('title' => t('Form'), 
    'help' => t('Form and type'), 
    'field' => array(
      'group' => 'donations',
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field', 
      'click sortable' => TRUE, 
      ),
      'sort' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_sort', 
      'filter' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
      ), 
      'argument' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
      ),
    ));  
  $data['GeneralDonations']['donationId'] = array('title' => t('ID'), 
    'help' => t('id'), 
    'field' => array(
      'group' => 'donations',
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field', 
      'click sortable' => TRUE, 
      ),  
      'sort' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_sort', 
      'filter' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
      ), 
      'argument' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
      ),
    ));
  $data['GeneralDonations']['donationDate'] = array('title' => t('Date'), 
    'help' => t('Date'), 
    'field' => array(
      'group' => 'donations',
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_date', 
      'click_sortable' => TRUE,     
      ), 
    'filter' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_date',),
    'sort' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_date',
      ),
    );

  return $data;
}
```

The column was set up in MySql this way: donationDate TIMESTAMP

I've been using drush to clear all my cache after each code change. I have used all the options. The only one that seems to show anything is the "ago" as it shows 45 years, 4 months so it appears it recognizes the unix epoch?

Still struggling with this. Is it something wrong with how I defined the mysql field, or is it views_handler_field_date? I see some methods but unsure how to troubleshoot this. I'm unsure which to dig into? thx, sam

thx, sam

Comment: Do you have the Date module installed?  Drupal doesn't handle date fields in core.

Comment: I didn't, I do now and have enabled it. Rechecked my settings for this field. Still blank. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the API is looking for an integer, particularly Unix timestamp and not the MySql timestamp which is transformed into a string. Looking at how Drupal handles the node table was key to grasping this and the hook_views_data documentation indicates that the field is an integer as well.